# How does Core Data work

Tags: xcode, core-data

Ive tried to gather information on as to how core data works, but can someone give me a clear explanation of all the stuff required...For instance NSDataContext, Fetchcontroller, NSDataModel, Presistent...

Perhaps all the steps involved to get a data...Now I'm also unclear about an SQLite file, like how do we load the data into the core data , once we have created our entities etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look is the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).  Is there a specific question you have that isn't answered there?

Comment: I'm just unclear as to how the data gets actually loaded do we create this sqlite file....

Comment: @Jason there are a couple of options for the persistent store.  Here's the specific link: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW1